# Capybara rspec test works without javascript but doesnt work with javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to test an upload form using capybara and rspec.  I am using the attach_file method.  When javascript is disabled the server recieves a mimi type of text/csv which is appropriate for the file. When the same test is run with javascript enabled the server recieves a mime type of application/octet-stream.

I tested the form in my browser with and without javascript enabled and the server receives the proper mime type, so it seems to be a problem in the testing framework.

Here are my tests

```
feature "User batch imports users" do
  scenario 'without js enabled' do
    login_user
    visit import_admin_users_path
    attach_file('Import users', "testassets/users.csv")
    click_button "Import Users"
    # Server recieves a mime type of text/csv
    expect(page).to_not have_content('File type not supported. Please upload a csv file.')
  end 

  scenario 'with js enabled', js: true do
    login_user
    visit import_admin_users_path
    attach_file('Import users', "testassets/users.csv")
    click_button "Import Users"
    # Server recieves a mime type of application/octet-stream
    expect(page).to_not have_content('File type not supported. Please upload a csv file.')
  end 
end
```

Anyone know whats going on here?